# read text file which contains JSONs using java

Tags: java

I have a txt file. It contains all json's. below is the sample data..
{"userid": "0be57386-b081-41fc-b5c4-98103956371f","segments":["2_GMC_L"]}{"userid": "57f2f319-ed9b-4dc9-a550-70b51b724acb","segments":["2_GMC_L"]}
{"userid": "ba009949-f658-4abe-a707-d2b460ee2046","segments":["2_GMC_L"]}
I have to get the whole data one json by json.. as a string values. and print...

Comment: "I have to get the whole data one json by json.. as a string values. and print..." Sweet, thanks for sharing and good luck!

Comment: @Sateesh Take the time to write a good question, to proof-read it and make sure it is complete, and to show that you have thought about the problem you are trying to solve. This will attract good answers. Just copying and pasting something is likely to get downvotes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONParser class for parsing JSONString, find below sample code.

```
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {

            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                    "/Users/Jiten/Documents/file1.txt"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
            String author = (String) jsonObject.get("author");
            JSONArray companyList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("companyList");

            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            System.out.println("Author: " + author);
            System.out.println("\nCompany List:");
            Iterator<String> iterator = companyList.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Why are we encouraging this garbage question? It shows zero research and adds very little (if any) value to SO.